# Reconciling Global and Virtual uWSGI installs

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi, pipenv

Deploying Django backend to an Ubuntu 18.04 AWS EC2. uWSGI, NGINX, and Django (everything) works fine when I launch from my pipenv shell's virtual environment. When I try to use a global uWSGI install for automated startup, uWSGI fails with the apparently common "module not found" error. Ubuntu system python is 2.7.15. My app runs 3.7.3 and runs virtual install of uWSGI compiled with 3.7.3.

I compiled a python3 uWSGI plugin from here: https://www.paulox.net/2019/03/13/how-to-use-uwsgi-with-python-3-7-in-ubuntu-18-x/
It fires, but still reports using python 2.7 (see example below).

I built an .ini and I've tried so many different combinations of settings, I lost track of which ones. I've tried setting the virtual environment in python path twice. I've tried setting different uWSGI binaries. I've adjusted permissions. Here is what it currently looks like:

```
[uwsgi]
pythonpath=/home/dpcii/.local/share/virtualenvs/tube-backend-django-S2uZEC9-/lib/python3.7/site-packages
pythonpath=/home/dpcii/.local/share/virtualenvs/tube-backend-django-S2uZEC9-/lib/python3.7/site-packages
plugins=python37
binary-path=/usr/bin/uwsgi
virtualenv=/home/dpcii/.local/share/virtualenvs/tube-backend-django-S2uZEC9-
pythonpath=/home/dpcii/.local/share/virtualenvs/tube-backend-django-S2uZEC9-/lib/python3.7/site-packages
chdir=/home/dpcii/tube-backend-django/
module=video_backend.wsgi:application
home=/home/dpcii/.local/share/virtualenvs/tube-backend-django-S2uZEC9-

master=false
processes=10
threads=2
socket=video_backend.sock
chmod-socket=666
vacuum=true
```

When I fire up the Emperor using global (instead of python environment) uWSGI executable, this is what I get:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15-debian (64bit) on [Mon Oct 28 12:57:50 2019] ***
compiled with version: 7.3.0 on 28 September 2018 15:41:15
os: Linux-4.15.0-1051-aws #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 18 13:35:53 UTC 2019
nodename: ip-172-30-0-12
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi
dropping root privileges as early as possible
chdir() to /home/dpcii/tube-backend-django/
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 3841
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address video_backend.sock fd 3
dropping root privileges after socket binding
Python version: 2.7.15+ (default, Oct  7 2019, 17:39:04)  [GCC 7.4.0]
Set PythonHome to /home/dpcii/.local/share/virtualenvs/tube-backend-django-S2uZEC9-
ImportError: No module named site
VACUUM: unix socket video_backend.sock removed.
Mon Oct 28 12:57:50 2019 - [emperor] curse the uwsgi instance twstartup.ini (pid: 21180)
Mon Oct 28 12:57:53 2019 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance twstartup.ini
```

This is the response I get from the working environment install:

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from twstartup.ini
open("./python37_plugin.so"): No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3724]
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./python37_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory !!!
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Mon Oct 28 13:45:44 2019] ***
compiled with version: 7.4.0 on 27 October 2019 18:59:30
os: Linux-4.15.0-1051-aws #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 18 13:35:53 UTC 2019
nodename: ip-172-30-0-12
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/dpcii/tube-backend-django
detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to /home/dpcii/tube-backend-django/
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 3841
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address video_backend.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 19:16:38)  [GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]]
Set PythonHome to /home/dpcii/.local/share/virtualenvs/tube-backend-django-S2uZEC9-
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x55e9527ff860
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 833440 bytes (813 KB) for 20 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
added /home/dpcii/.local/share/virtualenvs/tube-backend-django-S2uZEC9-/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ to pythonpath.
added /home/dpcii/.local/share/virtualenvs/tube-backend-django-S2uZEC9-/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ to pythonpath.
added /home/dpcii/.local/share/virtualenvs/tube-backend-django-S2uZEC9-/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ to pythonpath.
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x55e9527ff860 pid: 21229 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
```

It feels like I'm dancing around the answer. I have only a fingernail grip on python env pathing and symlinking, so it's possible there is something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: I noticed that I had two different versions of uwsgi, so I brought the global version up to 2.0.18. That didn't make a difference.

Comment: Python is such a PITA.  I wouldn't consider trying to install it without docker which makes versioning things soooo much easier